# Week seems to start on saturday in ActiveGantt

Tags: c#, winforms, gantt-chart

I am hoping to find a solution here, since the creator of ActiveGantt seems to have closed its doors.

ActiveGantt itself is a specialised library which provides a gantt-chart for using with c#, vb# and more.

Right here I am using it with C# in winforms.

I don't know why, but ActiveGantt seems to be using saturday as the start of a week, but in my region (germany) monday would be right.

[image]

The image shows the upper, middle and lower TierArea, all set to

```
TierType = E_TIERTYPE.ST_CUSTOM.
```

The LowerTier has an Interval of "1ww" which is the work week.
I am using the event "CustomTierDraw" to set the text and style, but apart from this I am doing nothing with it.

So why is the week starting on a saturday?

What I already checked:
 - "Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek" gives me Monday and thus tells me that the culture is correctly set.
 - The chart itself allows to set a culture which I set to "de-DE", but didn't make a difference. I even tried setting the cultures FirstDayOfWeek manually to monday, but it didn't work either.

Right now I am open for any suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Markus

Comment: Thanks for editing my question @MethodMan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to contact the original developer, and this is indeed a bug in ActiveGantt which was never fixed. (even not in higher versions)

Since the product is discontinued, the only available solution is to buy a source code licence from him and fix it myself.